# Use variable from another host

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook that executes a script on a Windows box that returns a value that I have to re-use later on in my playbook after switching to `localhost`.
How can I access this value after switching back to `localhost`?

Here is an example:

```yaml
- hosts: windows
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: Call PowerShell script
      win_command: "c:\\windows\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe c:\\psl_scripts\\getData.ps1"
      register: value_to_reuse

- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  
  tasks:
    - name: debug store_name from windows host
      debug:
        var: "{{ hostvars[windows][value_to_reuse][stdout_lines] }}"
```

What is the correct syntax accessing a variable from another host?
I'm receiving error message:

> "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'windows' is undefined

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the code that works for a group in a `loop`:

```yaml
- name: print value_to_reuse
  debug:
    var: hostvars[item].value_to_reuse.stdout_lines
  loop: "{{ groups['windows'] }}"
```

Same code works without iterations:

```yaml
- name: print value_to_reuse
 debug:
   var: hostvars[groups['windows'].0].value_to_reuse.stdout_lines
```

Comment: This is a common need, yet I don't see this use case anywhere but here, even in the docs.
For example, if you want to create a specific user on a single host, and access that users public SSH key so you can add it to all the rest of the hosts in the play, you would have to use this technique.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars['windows']['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']
```

Three mistakes:

- you should quote string values
- `var` parameter takes the variable name, not a template (which should be an `msg`-parameter value)
- `windows` in the given example should be the host name as all facts are bound to hosts, not group of hosts

Comment: Hi @techraf. With your changes no red color in the output anymore, but still doesn't show any value:  `"hostvars['windows']['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`

Comment: I've executed script like this: `hostvars['windows'] `  and got back only empty string: `"hostvars['windows']": ""`, meaning there is no variables registered for "windows" host. How is this possible if I do register it?

Comment: Is your host names `windows` or a host group?

Comment: I'm connecting to a Windows Server, and do have a hosts file:
`[windows]`
`1.1.1.1`
and `groups_vars/windows.yml` file with defined inventory variables as described here:
http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_windows.html

Comment: Hi @techraf, this code works with `with_items`:  

`- name: print value_to_reuse

  debug:

    var: hostvars[item]['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']

  with_items: "{{ groups['windows'] }}"`

Comment: If your hostname is `1.1.1.1`, you should use `hostvars['1.1.1.1']['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']`, **not** `hostvars['windows']`.

Comment: @techraf what if you need `['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']` for every host of group `['windows']`? I've tried loops: `- debug:
    var: hostvars['item']['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']
  with_items: "{{ groups['windows'] }}"` but it also gives me `"VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"`. I had success accessing hosts by indexes: `- debug:
      var: hostvars[groups['windows'][0]]['value_to_reuse']['stdout_lines']` but there's no luck when you have 10, 20 and more hosts, right? I didn't find construction to access all hosts (`['all']` doesn't work). Give advice, please.