# Executing playbooks in groupings created in hosts.yaml file

Tags: ansible, yaml, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

Ansible Version: 2.8.3

I have the following `hosts.yaml` file for use in Ansible

I have applications that I want to deploy on potentially both **rp_1** and **rp_2**

```yaml
---
all:
  vars:
    docker_network_name: devopsNet
    http_protocol:   http
    http_host:       ansiblenode01_new.example.com
    http_url:  "{{ http_protocol }}://{{ http_host }}:{{ http_port }}/{{ http_context }}"
  hosts:
    ansiblenode01_new.example.com:
    ansiblenode02_new.example.com:
  children:
    ##################################################################
    rp_1:
      children:
        httpd:
          hosts:
            ansiblenode01_new.example.com:
          vars:
            number_of_tools:    6
            outside_port:       443
            
        jenkins:
          hosts:
            ansiblenode01_new.example.com:
          vars:
            http_port: 4444
            http_context: jenkins
            
        artifactory:
          hosts:
            ansiblenode01_new.example.com:
          vars:
            http_port: 8000
            http_context: artifactory
            
    rp_2:
      children:
        httpd:
          hosts:
            ansiblenode02_new.example.com:
          vars:
            number_of_tools:    4
            outside_port:       7090
            
        jenkins:
          hosts:
            ansiblenode02_new.example.com:
          vars:
            http_port: 7990
            http_context: jenkins
            
        artifactory:
          hosts:
            ansiblenode02_new.example.com:
          vars:
            http_port: 8000
            http_context: artifactory
```

The following python wrapper script is calling ansible-playbook in a loop to deploy the applications

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

import yaml
import os
import getpass

with open('hosts.yaml') as f:
    var = yaml.load(f)

sudo_pass = getpass.getpass(prompt="Please enter sudo password: ")

# Running individual ansible-playbook deployment for each application listed and uncommented under 'applications' object.
for network in var['all']['children']:
    for app in var['all']['children'][network]['children']:
        os.system('ansible-playbook deploy.yml --extra-vars "application='+app+' ansible_sudo_password='+sudo_pass+'"')
```

The problem I recognize is that both Ansible and Python will use the hosts.yaml file, but not use it the way I thought it would as I'm not too familiar with Ansible.

The hosts.yaml was written in a format that is required by Ansible.

The Python script will open the yaml file, make a dictionary out of it, and step through the dictionary and look for the application names to pass to the command line call. The problem is then that Python only passes the name of the app as a string to the invocation of `ansible-playbook`, the dictionary structure obviously doesn't get passed, so Ansible will then open the `hosts.yaml` file as well, but all it does is step through the yaml and look for the first occurrence of the app name that was passed as an argument when `ansible-playbook` was invoked, completely disregarding the structure I've created in the yaml file.

So basically only the `rp_1` group in the yaml file will be executed since Ansible, I think reads through the yaml from top down and stops at the first occurrence, therefore all or parts of the `rp_2` group will never be processed by Ansible if the group contains all or some of the same apps as `rp_1`, therefore running the same deployment twice.

Is there a way to invoke Ansible or some ways to set the playbooks up so that Ansible will recognize that in my hosts file, I have networks (`rp_1`, `rp_2`) that I want to setup and executes the playbooks in the grouping that I've created in the yaml file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible already has this built-in. You do not need a wrapper script.

To run the `deploy.yml` playbook on all hosts in your `hosts.yaml` (this is called "inventory" btw.) do this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml deploy.yml -bK
```

To only run it on `rp_1`, do this:

```
ansible-playbook -i hosts.yaml deploy.yml --limit rp_1 -bK
```

- `-b` makes ansible become `root`
- `-K` will make ansible ask for the password to become `root`
- `-i <file>` specifies the inventory file
- `--limit <host/group>` limits the execution to certain hosts or groups, you can also add more than one, as a comma-separated list (e.g., `pr_1,rp_2`)

You can also specify a list of hosts/groups in your playbook like this:

```yaml
- name: do whatever you like
  hosts:
    - rp_1
    - rp_2
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "I'm running on {{ inventory_hostname }}!"
```

Further reading:

- [Discovering variables: facts and magic variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html)
- [How to build your inventory](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html)
- [Special variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html)
- [Using variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html)
- [Ansible examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible-examples)
- Accessing variables of "other" hosts: on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/638507/how-to-access-host-variable-of-a-different-host-with-ansible) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936489/ansible-use-variable-from-another-host)

Comment: I have some tasks in yml files and they're named "jenkins.yml", "httpd.yml", etc that I would like to include with the applications in each host group, how would I go about including the pertinent yml files for the apps included in each group to be executed during the deployment?

For example, if I have jenkins and httpd in hosts group rp_1, id like to include jenkins.yml and httpd.yml which are stored somewhere in the workspace of Ansible and contain tasks like shell scripts I want to execute for configuration

Comment: You specify in the play on which hosts or groups it will run. Just like I do it in the example (the last piece of code in my answer)

Comment: Is there something built into Ansible where I could dynamically include or reference the children in each host using jinja variables based on what is written in the hosts.yaml or would I have to figure out an implementation that lets Ansible dynamically include specific task yml files on my own?

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for to solve all my issues is a way for Ansible to tokenize the values in the hosts.yaml file not just in the vars section, but also the hosts section and all:children: ... , so I can reference those values as jinja variables for the sake of doing stuff like creating system messages and other operations where I'd like Ansible to do things dynamically.

Comment: Yes, all this is possible, but far out of scope for a single stackoverflow answer. You should look at conditionals with `when`, to run tasks conditionally and at the `hostvars` variable to access variables and facts of other hosts. But your questions suggests, that you would profit from spending a few hours reading the documentation or tutorials. I will include a few links in my answer.