# ansible loops the variables in the host file group

Tags: ansible-2.x

That's my group variable

```
[addnode]
10.102.26.53  hostname=add1 ansible_ssh_user=root
```

I want to loop through the value of the hostname variable in this group

This is my code

```
  tasks:
    - name: drain node
      shell: kubectl drain "{{item}}" --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
      with_items: "{{ groups['addnode'] }}"
```

I can only get the ip of the first row

What if we go through the second variable in this group, hostname

Comment: `hostvars[item].hostname`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use variable from another host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936489/use-variable-from-another-host)

Answer (score 0):

I tried this method and it works now

```
  tasks:
    - name: Gets the addnode group variables
      shell: echo "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }}"
      loop: "{{ groups.addnode }}"
      register: result

    - name: INSTALL JAR | Storage variable
      set_fact:
        addnode_hostname: "{{result}}"

    - debug: msg="{{addnode_hostname}}"

- name: Uninstall delete node
  hosts: "{{ hosts | default('kubeQ[0]') }}"
  gather_facts: no
  become: yes
  any_errors_fatal: true
  tasks:
    - name: drain node
      shell: kubectl drain "{{ hostvars[item].ansible_hostname }}" --delete-local-data --force --ignore-daemonsets
      loop: "{{ groups.addnode }}"
```