# ansible using variable in other host group

Tags: ansible

I want use variable created in web hosts at later stage in db hosts. Here is my current playbook
main playbook

```
- hosts: web_{{ env }}
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: "../roles/{{ role_name }}/tasks/gen_pwd.yml"

- hosts: db_{{ env }}
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: "../roles/{{ role_name }}/tasks/print_pwd.yml"
```

gen_pwd.yml

```
- name: Generate random password without special characters
  become: yes
  become_user: xyz
  command: "mkpasswd -l 6 -d 1 -c 1 -C 1 -s 0"
  register: _new_pwd
  run_once: true
  #delegate_to: localhost
  #no_log: true

- name: Store password in variable
  set_fact:
    plain_pwd: "{{ _new_pwd.stdout }}"
```

now i want to use variable plain_pwd in task that belongs to db host

print_pwd.yml

```
- name: Print password in scoring
  debug:
    msg: "{{ plain_pwd}}"


But I get "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'plain_pwd' is undefined. How can I fix this error ?
```

Comment: Extend the first play to run on `hosts: web_{{ env }}:db_{{ env }}` and you will get you var whatever the host in the next plays.

Comment: @Zeitounator I guess it would run task which generates password in db_{{env}} as well which i want to avoid.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand your problem then.

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936489/use-variable-from-another-host

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Zeitounator suggestion and addressing @sam's concerns:

```
- hosts: web_{{ env }}:db_{{ env }}
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - import_tasks: ../roles/{{ role_name }}/tasks/gen_pwd.yml
      when: "'web_' + env in group_names"

    - import_tasks: ../roles/{{ role_name }}/tasks/print_pwd.yml
      when: "'db_' + env in group_names"
```