# Ansible-Playbook Output as Variable for Email Notifications

Tags: ansible

I started experimenting with Ansible to manage all my Linux Servers easier.

I am trying to create a playbook that updates all the servers and sends an email notification.
The update works well, the only thing that I cant manage to get to work is the email notification.
I want to get a notification with the output of the playbook.

My take was to register each task and then take the output of it with .stdout , that didnt work sadly.

````
    - name: Update apt repo und cache auf alle server
      apt: update_cache=yes force_apt_get=yes cache_valid_time=3600
      register: aptrepo

    - name: Aktualisiert alle pakete
      apt: upgrade=dist force_apt_get=yes
      register: aptupgrade

    - name: Überprüfen ob ein Neustart benötigt wird
      register: reboot_required_file
      stat: path=/var/run/reboot-required get_md5=no

    - name: Neustarten wenn der Kernel der Maschine aktualisiert wurde
      reboot:
        msg: "Neustart wurde vom Ansible initiiert"
        connect_timeout: 5
        reboot_timeout: 300
        pre_reboot_delay: 0
        post_reboot_delay: 30
        test_command: uptime
      when: reboot_required_file.stat.exists
      
    - name: Senden Email an Ticketsystem
      mail:
        host: smtp.office365.com
        port: 587
        username: email.de
        password: "{{emailpw}}"
        from: "email.de"
        to: "email.de"
        subject: "[INTERN] - Linux Servern wurden aktualisiert"
        body: "Folgende Linux Server wurden erfolgreich aktualisiert: {{ play_hosts | to_yaml }}\nDiese wurden ggf. neugestartet falls der Kernel aktualisiert wurde!\nOutput: {{aptrepo.stdout}}"
        secure: starttls
      delegate_to: localhost
      run_once: true```
````

Comment: Each task has its specific output dictionary. Those information can be found in the relevant documentation, for example for the `reboot` module: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/reboot_module.html#return-values

Comment: The APT module should have an stdout return value. But like I said for me it doesnt work. I get the error `fatal: [GIGM-AppLinux -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'. 'dict object' has no attribute 'stdout'\n\nThe error appears to be in '/home/ansible-playbooks/update.yml': line 37, column 7, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n    - name: Senden Email an Ticketsystem\n      ^ here\n"}` .

Comment: You are misreading the documentation, then: [_"Returned: success, when needed"_](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/apt_module.html#return-stdout), so, in your case, the Ansible team didn't feel like `stdout` was needed. Probably because it is not installing any module but just an update of the cache?

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right, I never tried to get `stdout` from other tasks , the upgrade one delievered output. The registered task `aptupgrade.stdout` delivered output. 

Now I have a 2nd. question, is there a way how to get the output from each server? Right now it just outputs for 1 server.

Comment: Because you added `run_once: true`, so it only run for one of the servers.

Comment: Yes, because I just want to have everything in 1 email and not create for each server a email. I would like to format it like this: 
Server X Output:
Output result
Server y Output:
Output result etc..

Comment: Then you need to read about [`hostvars`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48936489/use-variable-from-another-host)